# Fibonacci sequence questions

Tags: number-theory, integer-sequence

I want to show that
"Out of the first 450 Fibonacci numbers, the odd number is twice as many as even number." with Mathematica.

Can you solve it please?

Comment: `Tally@Mod[Fibonacci@Range@450, 2]`

Comment: Actually, $F_n$ is even iff $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @lhf Yes, and by the construction principle of the Fibonacci number it is clear the the sequence contains always two consecutive odd numbers followed by an even one ;-)

Answer (score 10):

First the Fibonacci numbers

```
out = Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 450}];
```

then counting....

```
Mod[#, 2] & /@ out // Counts
```

(*<|1 -> 300, 0 -> 150|>*)

Comment: I'd use [`CountsBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountsBy.html) with `EvenQ` as the function instead of `Mod[#, 2]&`. The result is `<|False -> 300, True -> 150|>`.

Answer (score 8):

Let's find the conditions under which a Fibonacci number is odd or even. Happily, `Reduce` has us covered:

```
isOdd = Reduce[Mod[Fibonacci[n], 2] == 1, n, Integers]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && (n == 1 + 3 C[1] || n == 2 + 3 C[1]) *)

isEven = Reduce[Mod[Fibonacci[n], 2] == 0, n, Integers]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && (k == 0 && n == 3*C[1]) *)
```

This says for all integers $ n $, $ F_n \equiv 0\,\left(\bmod 2\right) $ when $ n \equiv 0 \left(\bmod 3\right) $.

Now, let's see how many instances there are of each for $n$ between $1$ and $450$.

```
evens = Length@FindInstance[isEven && 1 <= n <= 450, {n, C[1]}, Integers, 450]
(* 150 *)

odds = Length@FindInstance[isOdd && 1 <= n <= 450, {n, C[1]}, Integers, 450]
(* 300 *)
```

Now that we've come this far, Mathematica can also help us with the basic arithmetic:

```
2 * evens == odds
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to [mgamer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19726/mgamer)'s nice answer:

```
Mod[Array[Fibonacci, 450], 2]//Counts
```

> <|1 -> 300, 0 -> 150|>

**Edit**

To 'borrow' the neat suggestion made by [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer) in a comment to rgamer's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218719/106):

```
Array[Fibonacci, 450] // CountsBy[OddQ]
```

> <|True -> 300, False -> 150|>

**Edit 2**

[lhf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19574/lhf) points out in a comment that "$F_n$ is even iff $n$ is a multiple of 3"

```
Table[Fibonacci[n], {n,3, 450,3}] // CountsBy[EvenQ]
```

> ```
> <|True -> 150|>
> ```

A very interesting one, it seems to me. As long as $n$ is a multiple of 3, then "the odd number is twice as many as even number" as the OP asks for $n$ equal to 450.

Answer (score 4):

```
Array[Fibonacci, 450, 1, CountsBy[OddQ] @* List]
```

> ```
> <|True -> 300, False -> 150|>
> ```

Also

```
Array[Fibonacci /* OddQ, 450, 1, List /* Counts]
```

> ```
> <|True -> 300, False -> 150|>
> ```

and

```
450 // Range /* Fibonacci /* CountsBy[OddQ]
```

> ```
> <|True -> 300, False -> 150|>
> ```